# How to change android:textColorSecondary value in runtime android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-styles, android-toolbar

I have assigned `android:textColorSecondary` in `syles.xml` but I have a requirement to change those in runtime while selecting a button. So kindly suggest me whether this could be possible in runtime or not with your solutions. I have no idea about the behaviour in runtime. Thanks in advance. Any help would be useful for me.

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>   <!--checked color-->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>  <!--un checked color-->
    </style>
```

**Note:** In `styles.xml` am using `android:textColorSecondary` as `@color/secondary_text` because I am using it for default un checked color for Checkbox property. Thanks in advance.